# Performance Gain with Specifically Built OS

Tags: performance, operating-system

Let's take a trivial CPU bound program, such as brute forcing prime numbers, which perhaps occasionally saves them to an SD card.

Inefficiencies in today's programs include interpretation and virtual machines etc. So in the interest of speed, let's throw those away, and use a compiled language.

Now while we now have code that can run directly on the processor, we still have the operating system, which will multiplex between different processes, run its own code, manage memory and do other things that will slow down the execution of our program.

If we were to write our own operating system which solely runs our program, what factor of speedup could we expect to see?
I'm sure there might be a number of variables, so please elaborate if you want.

Comment: How did you conclude that VMs and interpreted languages are _inefficient_?

Comment: @aqua Generally speaking they take longer to load up and have greater overheads. For the sake of this question, you may use any language that maintains a similar processing speed to that of ASM.

Comment: I think your assumptions aren't valid. For example Python is an interpreted language but Python itself benefits from being written in C. VMs also come with their own pros and cons - calling VMs inefficient is a poor blanket statement IMO.

Comment: @aqua I haven't assumed anything. Take a look at [some benchmarking.](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64/benchmark.php?test=all&lang=python3&lang2=gcc&data=u64)

Comment: Just because C is faster than Python doesn't mean interpreted languages are inefficient. If that's all your comparison is based on then you're doing a whole lot of effort (writing your own OS) for not  much gain. You're better off just using C and optimizing on baremetal.

Comment: @aqua I wasn't saying they are inefficient, I was saying that include inefficiencies. As for the "whole lot of effort... for not much gain" that's exactly what the question was asking, how much gain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at products by Return Infinity http://www.returninfinity.com/ (I'm not affiliated in any way), and experiment.

My own supercomputing experience demonstrates, that skipping the TLB (almost entirely), by running a flat memory model, combined with lack of context switching between kernel and userland, can and does accelerate some tasks - especially those related to message passing in networking (MAC level, not even TCP, why bother), as well as brute force computation (due to lack of memory management).

On brute-force computation that exceeds the TLB or cache size, you can expect approx 5-15% performance gain compared to having to do RAM-based translation table lookups - the penalty is that each software error is entirely unguarded (you can lock some pages statically with monolithic linking, thou).

On high-bandwidth work, especially with a lot of small message-passing, you can easily obtain even 500% acceleration by going kernel-space, either by completely removing the (multi-tasking) OS, or by loading your application as a kernel driver, circumventing the entire abstraction as well. We've been able to push the network latency on MAC-layer pings from 18us down to 1.3us.

On computation that does fit inside L1 cache, I'd expect minimal improvement (around 1%).

Does it all matter? Yes and no. If your hardware costs vastly exceed your engineering costs, and you have done all the algorithmic improvements you can think of (better yet, proved that the computation done is exactly the computation required for the result!) - this can give meaningful perfomance benefits. Extra 3% (overall average success) on a supercomputer costing approx $8M/y in electricity, not including hardware amortization, is worth $24k/y. Enough to pay an engineer for a month to optimize the most common task it runs :).

Comment: I'm new to this; what is TLB?

Comment: TLB = Translation Look-aside Buffer. A special table is used to map virtual memory addresses to addresses in physical memory. The TLB caches part of that table so mapping memory addresses from virtual to physical can be done fast and efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're running a decent machine and the OS is not doing much else: Not a large factor, I'd expect less than a 10% improvement.

Just the OS 'idling' doesn't (shouldn't) take up much of the processing power of the CPU. If it is, you need a better machine, a better OS, a format or some combination of these.

If, on the other hand, you're running a bunch of other resource-intensive things, obviously expect that this can be sped up a lot by just *not* running those other things.

If you're not a super-user, you may be surprised to find that there are a ton of (non-OS) processes running in the background, these are more likely to take up CPU processing power that the OS.

Slightly off topic but related, keep in mind that, if you're running 8 cores, you can, in a perfect world, speed up the process by 8x by multi-threading.

Expect a *way* bigger improvement from known solutions to problems and making better use of data structures and algorithms, and, to a lesser extent, the choice of language and micro-optimizations.

From my experience:

Not the most scientific or trustable result but, most of the time when I open up Task Manager on Windows, all the OS processes are below 1% of the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

There is a super-computer answer, and a multi-cores answer already, so here is the GPGPU answer.

When a super-computer is overkill, but a multi-core CPU is under-powered, **and** your algorithm is sensibly parallelizable, consider adapting it to a GPGPU. Many of the benefits of a super-computer solution are available, in reduced form at reduced cost, by performing CPU-intensive tasks on a GPGPU.

[Here](http://cudafytuningtutorial.codeplex.com/) is a link to an analysis I performed last year on implementing, and tuning, a brute-force solution to the Travelling Salesman Problem using a *compute capability 2.0* NVIDIA Graphics card, [CUDAfy](http://cudafy.codeplex.com/), and C#.